# Getting data from MySQL database based on date

Tags: java, android, mysql, date, android-contentprovider

I have a table named Order consisting of 3 columns (id, date, price). I am trying to retrieve  all the data where `date >= startdate AND date <= endDate`. The dates in the column `date` are saved as `TEXT` in this format: `"MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss"` (`10-27-2013 12:12:43`)

I have tried the following SQL statements:

```
Cursor cursor = cr.query(PizzeriaContentProvider.CONTENT_URI_ORDER, null, PizzeriaDatabase.CELL_ORDER_DATE + " >= DATETIME ("+ startDate + ") AND " + 
                PizzeriaDatabase.CELL_ORDER_DATE + " <= DATETIME(" + endDate + ")", null, null);

Cursor cursor = cr.query(PizzeriaContentProvider.CONTENT_URI_ORDER, null, PizzeriaDatabase.CELL_ORDER_DATE + " between ( " + startDate + " AND " + endDate + ")", null, null);
```

But both of them throw the same exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{cz.vongrad.pizzeria/presentationLayer.ViewOrder}: 
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "14": syntax error: , 
while compiling: SELECT * FROM orders WHERE (date >= DATETIME(10-27-2013 14:01:53) AND date <= DATETIME(10-27-2013 14:01:53))
```

So I guess I compare the dates in a wrong format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

INVERTED COMMA's are missing::

```
Cursor cursor = cr.query(PizzeriaContentProvider.CONTENT_URI_ORDER, null, PizzeriaDatabase.CELL_ORDER_DATE + " >= DATETIME ('"+ startDate + "') AND " + 
                PizzeriaDatabase.CELL_ORDER_DATE + " <= DATETIME('" + endDate + "')", null, null);
```

Comment: Thanks, I did not know that it has to be between inverted commas. I will mark you answer accepted in 5 minutes, it does not allow me to do it now...

Comment: @Husky: Sure... Not an issue